# android virtual device that failed to load

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-virtual-device

When i launched the eclipse in window 7 I was getting an error message:

```
parseSdkContent failed
Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface
```

After doing some research i found a solution and deleted `~/.android` and restarted Eclipse but now I am getting another message saying:

```
a repairable android virtual device
that failed to load
```

I tried to reinstall the entire setup again but still I am getting this problem.

Answer (score 0):

To Solve Your current problem go to android sdk installation - platform-tools folder call adb.exe call adb.exe devices to see is the default virtual device 5557 if not try declare it manually 
In ADV when you configure your virtual device try to add memory and set external storage Try to Catch memory out of bound exception

Answer (score 0):

it happens if you have two or more version of SDK in same machine. Deleting .android is temporarily solve the problem. So try this solution:

```
1. Close Eclipse
```

2. Navigate to your sdk folder (something like C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk)
3. Go to platforms folder -> android-21 folder -> data folder and rename layoutlib.jar (for backup only)
4. Copy the same file (layoutlib.jar) from your android-20 folder to this folder "android-21"
5. Start Eclipse